# Using VBA to read new Outlook Email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code which tells when new message has arrived!

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    MsgBox "New Mail Has Arrived"
End Sub
```

How do I read the body,subject of this mail? Are there any good tutorials for outlook programming?

I found [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa155701%28v=office.10%29.aspx) tutorial which was useful but was general overview.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
Private WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
      Set olApp = Outlook.Application
      Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
      Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    MsgBox Msg.Subject
    MsgBox Msg.Body

  End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Paste the code into ThisOutlookSession and restart Outlook. When a message enters your default local Inbox you'll see the popup with subject and body.